# `ApplicationRunner` wait until other service is up

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have an `ApplicationRunner` to create an admin user on the first start of a spring boot application.

To create the user, it must connect to an auth server (we use `Keycloak`). However, if the service is deployed together with the main application (via `docker-compose up -d`) it will take some time until the auth server is available, actually, too long. The `ApplicationRunner` will fail with a `502 Bad Gateway` exception, because it is executed before the auth server is up and running.

How can the `ApplicationRunner` delay creating the admin until the auth server is up?

Ideally, the `ApplicationRunner` should delay everything and provide some information about the "waiting state" during startup. If after e.g. 1 min or so the auth server is not available during startup, the application run should fail.

**Notes**
We are using docker-compose version 3. We are looking for an application level solution, because docker-compose docs state that this should be handled on the application level.

Comment: Do the techniques in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) work for you, or do you need something more directly written into the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, the startup procedure may just fail the complete application run, because it is an initialization script. Without success of this initialization the complete application cannot be used. The context / deployment should handle when to (re)start what.

If the initialization script fails (and consequently the complete application run), then using `docker-compose`'s `restart: unless-stopped` configuration on the main application will just retry starting it. Eventually, the auth server gets up in the meantime and finally the main service is up running.

Turns out that implementing `ApplicationRunner` it is not as easy to stop the complete application context during startup. Instead, implementing [SmartLifecycle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) and moving the logic into `start()` is a better idea. The method may just throw an exception to fail the application run on startup.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use Docker-Compose, you can [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

```
my-service:
    image: my-company/my-service:1.0.0
    container_name: my-service
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      my-auth-server-service:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

my-auth-server-service:
   image: ...
   container_name: ...
   ...
```

However, it doesn't guarantee the "readiness" of the service itself so an application-specific health or readiness check would be required (also described in the link above).

You might want define [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) in the Dockerfile of the authorization `my-auth-server-service` service (feel free to do in every service) to detect the health/readiness through a REST API call. As long as you use Spring, the actuator endpoint is suitable.

Here is a short example, however, you might want to define additional/custom logic being able to detect the *complete readiness*.

```
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

HEALTHCHECK --interval=20s --timeout=3s --retries=20 \
    CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/actuator/health || exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but docker-compose docs state: "Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.". Also they hint, that this problem should not be solved in docker-compose but rather in the application code, which I originally posted the question tagged only as `spring boot`.

Comment: Why did you mention docker-compose if you want to find a solution on the application level (tagged [tag:spring-boot]? The details of your question including the start-up desciption implies you are looking for a solution on the [tag:docker-compose] level. Moreover, you haven't stated you use the version 3. Please, edit the question to get more helpful asnwers.

Comment: ...because it is related to the deployment and providing context information may help better understanding the question. Version 3 is the current version as of the date of the question - I added notes to clarify things in the question anyway.

Comment: There is no reason why this answer, full of so much valuable content, be DVed. If the question is not clear, the answer should not be penalized IMO.